# When I Use from Ioc Configuration I Get Error About (cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method )

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, unity-container

When I Use from `UnityResolver` in Web API Project , I get a error about Use from Generic Class or Interface. For example my `IPersonRepository` use from `IBaseRepository` and also my `PersonRepository` Class use from `BaseRepository`. Now, I want to register these classes in order to apply IoC .

My `IPersonRepository` Interface is

```
public interface IPersonRepository : IBaseRepository<Person>
{
}
```

and my `PersonRepository` Class is

```
public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository<Person>
{
    public PersonRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I use from `UnityContainer` to register it with below code.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

But I get this Erorr.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0311 The type 'RepositoryTest.Repository.PersonRepository' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(IUnityContainer, LifetimeManager, params InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'RepositoryTest.Repository.PersonRepository' to 'RepositoryTest.IRepository.IPersonRepository'.

How to Resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PersonRepository` also needs to be derived from the interface for them to be associated.

`PersonRepository` Class should be...

```
public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository<Person>, IPersonRepository {
    public PersonRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Because there must be an implicit reference conversion from the implementation to the abstraction.

That is what the error message is telling you.